# Using Select Option's value to query database

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have the following code to generate my option:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT MyID FROM database";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$option = "";
foreach ($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $rows) {
    $id = $rows[MyID];
    $option.="<option>".$id."</option>";
}
?>

<select name="options" id="options" class="options"> 
<option value="$id">Select an Option</option>
<?php echo $option?>
</select>
```

I would like to use the value of the selected option in my next query.. like this:

```
<?php
$myDB= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE RowID = :option");
$myDB->bindParam(':option', $option); //the value of the option selected in my dropdown
$myDB->execute();
$result = $myDB->fetchAll();
```

This is not working for some reason. Can you please help on this. Thanks

Comment: $options should be in either $_POST or $_GET super globals

Comment: Are you sending the selected value to the server and if yes, how?

Comment: Also it's `$rows['MyID']` and not `$rows[MyID]`, note the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks all for the comment. @jeroen no I am not sending the value to the server. I thought this is unneccesary since i'll be using the selected value to query right away

Comment: @user3045800 php runs on the server before the output is sent to the visitor. If you want to run php after the page has already loaded, you need ajax - a combination of javascript and php - to make a request to the server and get back / process the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT MyID FROM database";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$option = "";
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $id = $row['MyID'];
    $option.='<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
}
?>
<form method="post" action"(`The url of the next page`)">
<select name="options" id="options" class="options"> 
<option disabled>Select an Option</option>
<?php echo $option?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Next page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['options'])) {

    $option = $_POST['option'];
    $myDB= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE RowID = :option");
    $myDB->bindParam(':option', $option); //the value of the option selected in my dropdown
    $myDB->execute();
    $result = $myDB->fetchAll();
}
```

1. With `fetchAll()` you should assign this to a variable and then loop through that.
2. `$row[MyID]` MyID should be wrapped in '' or "" as the index is a string so `$row['MyId']`
3. You'll need to submit the data back to the server for PHP to be able to do anything with it as PHP creates he HTML and then sends it from the server to the browser.
4. I've used `if(isset())` for the REQUEST variables ($_GET, $_POST), this will prevent PHP from throwing errors if you try and load the page without them being available.

If you have any other questions, I'd be happy to help.

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['options'])) {

    $option = $_GET['option'];
    $myDB= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE RowID = :option");
    $myDB->bindParam(':option', $option); //the value of the option selected in my dropdown
    $myDB->execute();
    $result = $myDB->fetchAll();

    /**
     * You'll need to put the logic for the query above here
     **/   
} else {        

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT MyID FROM database";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $option = "";
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row['MyID'];
        $option.='<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
    }
?>

    <form method="get" action"">
    <select name="options" id="options" class="options"> 
    <option disabled>Select an Option</option>
    <?php echo $option?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
<?php
} // End of else
?>
```

I've also changed the form method to get and removed the action, so it will submit to the current page.

Comment: thanks for the help. really informative. but a question is that can I send the form data to same page i.e. <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>. I would like to do this and still get the same result. basically i would like to display a table based on the query on the same page

Comment: @user3045800, I've added an edit to my answer to show what I think you mean. This will mean that you only have the one page. Hope this helps!